# Weird "Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_x_continuous Error"

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, time-series

I have an interesting conundrum.  I can create the type of chart I seek interactively, but not automatically.  Or, I nearly had it automatically, but something broke. (example data at end of post).

I have my loop working the way I would like, but have run into errors when I add some geom_vline() statements (for us, denoting significant changes in our production environment).  I've tried working through it outside of the loop and am able to recreate the issue with details below. 

I have the following steps:

- create a vector with the list of changes:

`changeVector <- c(as.Date("2011-11-30"),as.Date("2011-12-05"))`

- [WORKS] create a plot with the data below, and it works:

`ggplot(df,aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP))+geom_line(aes(group=REGION,color=REGION))`

- [WORKS] try to add the geom_vline(xintercept=c(15308,15313)), and it works (but *only* if the geom_vline is at the end):

`ggplot(df,aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP))+geom_line(aes(group=REGION,color=REGION))+geom_vline(xintercept=c(15308,15313))`

- [FAIL] try to add the geom_vline(xintercept=changeVector) - I had problems with this for some reason, and had to add as.numeric to recognize the vector values properly:

`ggplot(df,aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP))+geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(changeVector))+geom_line(aes(group=REGION,color=REGION))`

When this step runs, I get the wonderfully useful error message:
`Error: Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_x_continuous.`

So, any ideas?  If I try to add an aesthetic component to the geom_vline, I still make no progress.  My desire was to have the geom_vline preceding the geom_line because the vline is context, not data.

Thank you for your help!

Here is a subset of the data (dataFile name df):

```
OBSDATE REGION COUNT AVG_RESP
2011-11-29     EMEA   293 4.430375
2011-11-30     EMEA   299 4.802876
2011-12-01     EMEA   292 4.362363
2011-12-02     EMEA   293 4.209829
2011-12-03     EMEA   294 4.262959
2011-12-04     EMEA   294 4.207959
2011-12-05     EMEA   293 4.172594
2011-12-06     EMEA   293 4.230887
2011-12-07     EMEA   298 4.259329
2011-12-08     EMEA   293 4.197645
2011-11-29 Americas   296 2.841182
2011-11-30 Americas   296 2.932196
2011-12-01 Americas   292 2.766438
2011-12-02 Americas   293 2.819556
2011-12-03 Americas   291 2.710584
2011-12-04 Americas   295 2.728407
2011-12-05 Americas   290 2.764310
2011-12-06 Americas   290 2.817483
2011-12-07 Americas   295 2.733864
2011-12-08 Americas   291 2.732405
2011-11-29     APAC   328 7.294024
2011-11-30     APAC   325 7.091046
2011-12-01     APAC   314 6.969236
2011-12-02     APAC   327 6.920428
2011-12-03     APAC   325 7.226308
2011-12-04     APAC   324 7.046296
2011-12-05     APAC   318 7.075094
2011-12-06     APAC   317 7.016467
2011-12-07     APAC   318 7.187358
2011-12-08     APAC   318 7.310220
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why it is doing that, but here is a workaround that keeps the vertical lines behind the data lines:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP)) + 
  geom_blank() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(changeVector)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=REGION,color=REGION))
```

EDIT:

Here is another workaround: explicitly specify that the x axis is to be a date, rather than have ggplot guess. When it guesses, it looks at the first layer plotted, which is the vertical lines. Given that the `xintercept` have to be given as numbers rather than dates, the x axis is assumed to be continuous/numeric. When the next layer is drawn, the dates of the x axis can not be mapped onto that and an error is thrown.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=OBSDATE,y=AVG_RESP)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(changeVector)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=REGION,color=REGION)) +
  scale_x_date()
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian!
Seems a little "hacky" but if it works, it works!

Comment: The scale_x_date() solution has me convinced this isn't a bug, and even makes a certain amount of sense. Tough to document though in a way that people would discover.

Comment: That EDIT is definitely a better approach.  I just never would have guessed it to be that way.  @joran, the "as.numeric" isn't necessary when using scale_x_date() - at least it wasn't necessary for me.

Comment: It took so much time for me to find the same issue. scale_x_datetime and geom_vline would work independently but not together. When i added  aes(xintercept=as.numeric(..) within geom_vline it worked.